# Linear Model Issue

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to train a simple linear model, and for some reason, it keeps running into an error, as it doesn't like the shape of the data. Does anyone know the way to make this work? I tried various reshaping techniques but each time it ran into issues (e.g. .reshape or .values.reshape).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import sklearn.linear_model 

#create data 
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['First']=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df1['Second']=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]

x=df1['First']
y=df1['Second']

#select model 
model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

#train
model.fit(x,y)

#predict 
X_new = [[5]]
print(model.predict(X_new))
```

Comment: Add batch dimensions in `x` i.e use `x = df1[['First']]`

Comment: Please post the full error trace; remove all code that may come *after* the error.

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn` classifiers such as [`LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) always take `X` as a 2D *arraylike* in the shape of N_samples x N_features. Reshaping `X` with `(-1, 1)` transforms the list into a 10 x 1 array.

```py
import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# data
X = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y = np.asarray([2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20])

# create DataFrame
# df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'First': X, 'Second': y})

# select model 
model = LinearRegression()
# train model -> 2D array for X
model.fit(X.reshape((-1, 1)), y)

# predict 
X_new = [[5]]
print(model.predict(X_new))
```

Also (and I'm assuming you need it later) you don't need `pandas.DataFrame`s at all for this.